# Gridview controls first event

Tags: asp.net

Gridview controls first event that gets fired

I have a Gridview control on an .aspx page. what is the first gridview control event, that gets triggered/fired.

Comment: This might help: [GridView Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events(v=vs.80).aspx), http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50540/GridView-Event-Handling

Answer (score 0):

Init() Occurs when the server control is initialized, which is the first step in its life cycle which is inherited from Control.